# SignalR overwriting OnConnected(), OnDisconnected()

Tags: signalr, signalr-hub

I'm trying to overwrite `OnConnected()`, `OnDisconnected()` methods but I get:

```
OnConnected()': no suitable method found to override
```

Is implementing `IDisconnect`, `IConnect` interfaces and doing my processing within `Connect()` and `Disconnect()` the same as `OnConnected()`, `OnDisconnected()`?

what gives?

```cs
public static class UserHandler
{
    public static HashSet<string> ConnectedIds = new HashSet<string>();
}

public class MyHub : Hub
{
    public override Task OnConnected()
    {
        UserHandler.ConnectedIds.Add(Context.ConnectionId);
        return base.OnConnected();
    }

    public override Task OnDisconnected()
    {
        UserHandler.ConnectedIds.Remove(Context.ConnectionId);
        return base.OnDisconnected();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're probably using and old version of SignalR. Read this http://weblogs.asp.net/davidfowler/archive/2012/11/11/microsoft-asp-net-signalr.aspx.

Answer (score 12):

This code worked for me until this morning when I upgraded SignalR from 2.1.0 to 2.1.1, and now I get "no suitable method found to override" for OnDisconnected().  I believe it needs to be written like this instead to account for a new parameter:

```cs
public override Task OnDisconnected(bool stopCalled = true) 
{
   UserHandler.ConnectedIds.Remove(Context.ConnectionId);
   return base.OnDisconnected(stopCalled); 
}
```

Comment: Just looking now after hours of learning SignalR 2 vs 1, you shouldnt really add the `= true` default. Because that will be false, if the timeout fires, and you can then have logic to adjust certain things, like time last seen, or set other parameters.