# SignalR OnConnected & OnDisconnected with Signin & Signout

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, signalr

My Scenario is construct the website with custom Authentication, there's menu transition by mouse click, and because of the some custom tool, we will use the window.location to change the page;

But with the login and out been used to calculate the daily report of each login/out user, we have to prevent the user just close the browser tab or close button;

And by search, there's no proper method to distinguish the reload and close, then we tried to use signalR to deal with these situation.

Is there any idea to detect the user's OnConnected & OnDisconnected triggered by reload or by close tab/browser?

Comment: have a look at [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13524046/signalr-overwriting-onconnected-ondisconnected?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

Please try this one, i think is should be helpful for you.

**Javascript**

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(e){
    var msg = 'Are you sure?';
    e = e || window.event;

    if(e)
        e.returnValue = msg;

    // Your OnDisconnected event here (SignalR)
}
```

**Jquery**

```
$(window).unload(function() {
   // Your OnDisconnected event here (SignalR)
});
```